# How to get the place values of numbers in a float?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

How can I get the place value of each number in a given float (ex: 32.578).

This should output something like:

```
tens: 3,
ones: 2,
tenth: 5
hundredth: 7
thousandth: 8
```

Is there any module that offers such a function?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard module that will do this. You could try writing it yourself though

Comment: An approach would be to divide the float x by 10 (x//10), and store the integer part of that division (your "tens"). Subtract the product of 10 and tens from x, and you have the "ones" as the integer part. Subtract the ones from x, multiply by 10, and the integer part of that product is your "tenth", and so forth. Yet most programmers here don't want to write code for somebody if that somebody does not provide any code s/he has written to tackle the problem. Otherwise some here feel they are to do homework for others. This also might be the reason why your request garnered two downvotes.

Comment: @Progg I am not looking for someone to write code or solve this specific problem. My question was whether such a function already exists as I could not find any, so as not to build a hard-coded function. I was looking for something more generic and flexible if such a thing already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient probably will likely be the string cast instead of algebraic modulos or logarithms.

```
number = str(32.578)
integers, decimals = number.split(".")

for digit in integers[::-1]:
    # will iterate over
    # ones, tens, 100s, ...

for decimal in decimals:
    # iterates over your decimals
```

And store/print them accordingly

Comment: In my experience, string operations are less efficient (slower) than modulo operations. And there shouldn't be any need to invoke logarithms for this problem.